# UWP "Invalid attribute value Unknown for property BorderThickness." while navigating to new Frame

Tags: xaml, uwp

While trying to navigate from one Page to another, I'm getting this "Invalid attribute value Unknown for property BorderThickness." error.

If I step through the code in the debugger everything works fine.  If I let the navigation happen on it's own, the code crashes.

Outside of setting BorderThickness to specific (integer) values or using the built-in ThemeResources, these values are not ever tied to bound values that might be null or have an unexpected value.

This code was working fine at one point, but that seems to have come to an end this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not certain why this is an issue, but I can identify specifically where the error is occurring.

```
    public async void OnLevelUp(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        LevelUpVm.CharacterId = IoC.Game.GetCharacter(SelectedCharacter.Id).Id;

        **await IoC.SaveConfigFile();** <<< OFFENDING LINE OF CODE

        var rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
        rootFrame?.Navigate(typeof(LevelUpView), null);

        IsBusy = false;

    }
```

If I move the OFFENDING LINE OF CODE after the rootFrame?Navigate line, it works fine.

So, after 5 hours of messing with the code, I've come to a solution - but I'm still not certain why the await call causes the problem.